# Are these two questions asking the same thing?

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, submanifold, diffeomorphism

Question $(I).$

Show that if the $n$-dimensional manifold $M$ is a product of spheres, then there exists an embedding $M \to \mathbb R^{n+1}.$

Question $(2).$

Show that there exists an embedding $S^{n_1} \times \dots \times S^{n_k} \to \mathbb R^{1 + \sum_{i = 1}^{k}n_i}$

Are these two questions asking the same thing? Is $S^{n_1} \times \dots \times S^{n_k}$ necessarily an $n$-dimensional manifold?

Comment: What are your thoughts?  You expect users to do your thinking for you?  Yet again. Please include context you lack, once again.

Comment: I thought that the two questions are the same @amWhy but I was not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

If $n=n_1+\cdots + n_k$, then $M$ is an $n$-dimensional manifold that is a product of spheres if and only if $M=S^{n_1}\times\cdots\times S^{n_k}$. The two questions are identical.